# Get Time From String - Perl

Tags: perl

In php you could just do

`strtotime("+1 days");`

And get the machine time for the next day.

I want to try the same with Perl, I'm going to be doing a sort of cron job to execute certain methods.

I know you could it use `str2time` from the module http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Date-6.02/lib/HTTP/Date.pm I just can't seem to figure it out.

I tried the following, but I'm unsure if I did it right

```
use HTTP::Date qw(str2time);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $lol = localtime();
my $time = $lol - ONE_HOUR*($lol->hour + 24);

print "Time: " . str2time($time);
```

Comment: Be careful, a day is not always 24 hours long if your time zone has daylight savings. If your system's time zone is set to UTC, you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t1 = localtime() + ONE_DAY;

print $t1->epoch;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tool for the job here is [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.29/Piece.pm).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $this_time = localtime();
print $this_time + 60*60*24,"\n";
```